# How to do div after div in page order

Tags: html, css

I'm beginner in CSS, I can't put div after

For example **:**
I want to put `red` div after `green` div as the image shows:

[image]

but I want to make divs **sticking to the edges of the screen** .

What I tried **:**

```css
.green {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 
 .red {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="green">
  
</div>

<div class="red">

</div>
```

Comment: Explain what's NOT working about your existing implementation. Preferably within your question rather than in comments. Also, I don't understand this: "i can't put div after for example."

Comment: If you want them vertically stacked you can just remove the `position: absolute;` ! (and the `left, top` parts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just write this code with relative positions I think will do the work. But following your example (where you set the position as absolute) I let you the following code. I don't know if it is what do you expect, if it isn't, please com back with more details.

```css
.green {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 
 .red {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateY(100%);
 }
```

```html
<div class="green">
  
</div>

<div class="red">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `top` + `bottom`. To span the entire width you could also use: `left + righ: 0`.

To shorten the code you can also use the `inset`-property with a 3 value syntax:
`inset: [top] [left/right] [bottom]`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.green {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: green;
 }
 
 .red {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 50% 0 0;
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="green">
  
</div>

<div class="red">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` (viewport width) units to set height relative to the viewport.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.green {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: green;
 }
 
 .red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="green">
  
</div>

<div class="red">

</div>
```

Comment: depends on the use-case. If the content is added that would blow the viewport then this would break. Then you would need to use `min-height`. If then additionally both boxes should remain to have the same height as each other you would need `CSS-Grid` + `grid-auto-rows: 1fr`. While this might be viable we miss information and details to know what this is used for.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because red div is overlapping your green div

so just change your code into this:

```css
.green{
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 100%;
       height: 50%;
       background-color: green;
       margin-bottom: 5px;
           }
 
      .red {
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 0;
       width: 100%;
       height: 50%;
       background-color: red;
            }
```

```html
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The big question is, what do you mean by

> i want to put red div after green div

Your browser reads its given html-code from left to right and from top to bottom, until you define something different in your CSS. This means "after" can also mean an alignment of your red div on the right edge of your green div.

But all you need is basically the snippet down below.
If you want them to be align centered (like shown in your screenshot), just add "margin: 0 auto" and you good to go.

I personally can only recommend testing positioning, as a beginner, with absolute values like "px" instead of relative values like percentage. This makes it much easier to understand what's happening.

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  // margin: 0 auto;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  // margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
</div>
<div class="red">
</div>
```

! of Course, if you run the code you have to remove the comment signs !